# Lambda expression to count distinct rows in a table

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to switch from Linq to lambda expression. I want the count of distinct rows in my table.

Is there a better way to get it that the one below?

```
 var count = _db.myTable
     .Where(i=>i.DATE.HasValue && i.DATE==DateFrom)
     .AsEnumerable()
     .Select(x=>x.myTable_ID)
     .Distinct()
     .Count();
```

Comment: Well I'd put the code on multiple lines, but other than that... what kind of "better" are you looking for? (Are you sure you need the `AsEnumerable()` call?)

Comment: I don't know!! That's why I'm asking. That's how I found it on the web and it seams to be working, but I'm not sure if it is the optimal way and I am going through quite a number of rows.

Comment: @GiotaB If you're having a bit of trouble converting it to Lambda, check out [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). When you enter a linq query expression, it will have a result tab which contains the expression as a Lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to switch from Linq to lambda expression.

It's not clear what you mean by that, but the lambda form is still using LINQ - if you mean you had a query expression before, it's worth being aware that query expressions are just transformed into non-query expression code by the compiler.

In terms of your actual query, you should get rid of the `AsEnumerable()` call, as otherwise you'll be performing everything after that in your .NET process rather than asking the database to do it. So simply:

```
var count = _db.myTable
     .Where(i => i.DATE.HasValue && i.DATE == DateFrom)
     .Select(x => x.myTable_ID)
     .Distinct()
     .Count();
```

After making sure that still works, you should check the generated SQL - it should be doing all the counting in the database, basically.

You should also see whether you really need the `i.DATE.HasValue` check, too - I suspect you don't, as if `DateFrom` is non-nullable, it'll only match non-null values of `DATE` anyway.

Comment: Up till now I was using the Linq syntax and now I was asked to start writing using only lambda. I'm also certain that I do need the `i.DATE.HasValue` because it is a parameter in my method and it can be null `DateTime? DateFrom`

Comment: @GiotaB: If it's null, it's not going to match anything - so why would you want the parameter to be nullable?

Comment: The program is aiming to sync 2 dbs. It should run every other day and retrieve data 2 days back. But the first time it should retrieve everything.

Comment: @GiotaB: So presumably there are two different queries involved? In that case you can use `DateTime concreteDate = DateFrom.Value;` and then just `.Where(i => i.DATE == concreteDate)` in the query.

Comment: You are correct. I don't need `i.DATE.HasValue` cause `DateFrom` will always have a value. The first time the app will run the user will provide a date (even if it is 1/1/1900) and after that the date will be calculated by `DateFrom = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-numberOfDaysToSkip)` where `numberOfDaysToSkip` is a const of 2 retrieved from the config file. There is one method `myMethod(DateTime? DateFrom)` running one query by the way...